# Set column count manually in React native listview

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native, grid

What could be the best way to set the number of columns in react list view(Native).
I need to set the number of columns as 5 in bigger screens.
Any hints in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Arun

Comment: Sort of out of scope but is there a reason you're using `ListView` and not `FlatList` at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should adjust you `ListView.DataSource` based on the dimensions of the user's device. I would use the `Dimension` API to get the user's device size and adjust the number of rows/columns in the list view's data source accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I just took the device width and divided into 5 (my case, i need only 5 column if the device is a tablet) and by 2 for phones and applied it to the grid cell component. Its looks fine but  feels a little hard while scrolling the content.